ARM template auto parameterisation
I'm working on a Logic App migration process. The idea being I take my DEV logic app and deploy seamlessly to UAT
This is a consumption logic app (not standard) so I believe a bunch of CI/CD functionality is missing. I've done some reading on deployment processes and they seem to point at a third party library to support it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76206803/1690193
Using a third party library is going to be difficult so I'm investigating my own solution to do this.
I'm exporting ARM templates for API connections and workflows. with the intention of deploying to other environments.
Inside the exported ARM template I get things like this:
"location": "australiaeast"
"id": "/subscriptions/c2cebxxx-xxxx-4778-xxxx-xxxad7c3xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/australiaeast/managedApis/office365"
So if I was to try and deploy this as-is to a new subscription and resource group this will just take this old identifier with it
So I'm busy writing powershell to turn this into ARM template functions like this:
"location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
"id": "[concat(subscription().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/',resourceGroup().location,'/managedApis/office365')]"
This will allow the ARM template to actually inherit the sub and RG that I give it at deploy time.
Questions:
A. Is there any API in Azure or Powershell library that will do this automatically? Replace sepcific subscription id's with ARM functions
B. Is there any Azure native support around migration of logic apps to other environments?

Sure a name can be different. It's not really too important to me at this time.

It could be hard to get answer if you have several queries in the ticket, recommend to edit and focus on one. In addition, what do you mean Am I missing something about how Logic Apps and connections work? , what detail have you done, and issue appearance?

Fair point I will simplify and clarify

There isn’t a specific Azure API or PowerShell library that automatically replaces subscription IDs with ARM functions. But you can use the ARM template function as you did.  For the 2nd query, probably you can check the doc for your reference. Please clarify detail query if you need help from devops.

Thanks @wadezhou-MSFT I appreciate your response. The specific issue with the given MS example is that, if we are use an ARM export of an existing Logic App, the testuri parameter is not automatically included, we need to find a way to manually inject it. It's fine, I just need to confirm that writing manual powershell is the only way to do this.

You need to prepare the ARM template via either PowerShell or automation CICD tool, like devops. If you checking for automation, consider replace token task in devops, which will replace the value in ARM json.

Thanks. I've written all the replace powershell now utilising regex. But I'm only working this out by manually inspecting the exported JSON

I think you should code the logicapp arm template from scratch with the reference of exported json template, instead of replacing ids. Exported json template need several changes before can be deployed.

Sure, if you have queries, you can raise a new ticket with minimum ARM template sample and detail appearance, which could help for troubleshooting.
